# About Refund api, RefundTransaction api

Tags: paypal

I'm using Paypal's classic API.
What's the difference between Refund API(in the adaptive payment) and RefundTransaction API(in the merchant package)? When should I use the RefundTransaction API? And any time limit with the Refund API? I know  the RefundTransaction API limits within 60 days.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal Adaptive payments require a developer account to have submitted an application for Adaptive Payment APIs and receive approval to use the APIs through PayPal.

If you are not approved to use PayPal Adaptive Payments APIs you should be using the regular Refund Transaction APIs.

[Adaptive Payments Information](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/)

Just in case you need it here is information on refunding payments:

[Refunding Payments Basic APIs](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/RefundTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/)

All standard PayPal Accounts are setup with a 60 day refund limit by default.

Comment: Thanks for your information. I've read Paypal document but not found any limitation on Refund API. With Refund API no time limit? And what about the transaction fees? The two APIs cost the same?

Comment: This is from the PayPal user agreement. This is for direct PayPal Transactions, and not Payflow transactions. [PayPal User Agreement](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/ua/useragreement-full?bn_r=o#8)
If you refund a Purchase Payment, we will retain the fixed fee portion of the Purchase Payment Fee. The buyer’s Account will be credited with the full Purchase Payment amount and the fixed fee portion of the Purchase Payment Fee will be deducted from your Account in addition to the amount of the refunded payment.

Comment: If you need to extend the refund time period, you may want to consider getting approval from PayPal for Non-Referenced credits. This is something that requires PayPal Approval. Here is the documentation on [Non-Referenced Credits](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoNonReferencedCredit_API_Operation_SOAP)

Comment: Thanks for your comment about the transaction fees. And whatow about the other question, are there any limitations on the Refund API. If no limitaions on it why should I consider RefundTransaction API. I can just use the Refund API, right?

Comment: The only limitation of the Refund APIs is you cannot refund a payment made greater than 60 days from the initial transaction date for PayPal Payments Standard Accounts.

Comment: It seems that they have the same limitation on the refund deadline. So the only critical difference between the two APIs is if it need to get the approval?

Comment: If you are asking about non-referenced credits, there is no time limit for them. This is because there is no transaction id associated with them. It requires approval through PayPal. Here is the information on the API Calls[PayPal non-referenced credits](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoNonReferencedCredit_API_Operation_SOAP)

Comment: I don't interest in non-referenced credits. I just wanted to know the key difference between the Refund API and the RefundTransaction API. the conclusion is both of them have 60-day time limit and using the Refund API need to get approval, whereas using the RefundTransaction API do not. right?

Comment: Here is the information on Refund API Operations. The only thing that needs to be done, is in the Third Party API permissions need to be granted within the PayPal Account. If you need it [This is the documentation on API Refund Operations](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Refund_API_Operation).It still has the 60 day time limit on either option.

Comment: It seems no evident difference between two APIs. I'm using the Refund API. Are there any cases that I should use the RefundTransaction API Or better to use the RefundTransaction API? Why does Paypal offer two refund apis?